# Are ballroom dance competitions just for trophies only?

Tags: tournaments, dancing

I visited several dancesports web sites, such as the [2018 New England Dancesports Championships](http://nedancesport.org/welcome.html), and I only see entry fees mentioned.

There is no mention of any prizes. What are the prizes? Are dance competitions just for flowers and trophies?

Answer (score 1):

The dance competition you linked to is an amateur competition. However, there are professional dance competitions with prize money, such as the [United States Dance Championships](http://unitedstatesdancechampionships.com/prizes-money/).